Grails gorm save method giving required checked transaction error with transaction block
I am using grails 5.2.5. I have a method where gate pass transaction is happening. Within this transaction I am trying to update some other domain. The value is updated but the following error shows in browser:
    URI
/myApp/genericGatePass/issue
Class
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException
Message
no transaction is in progress
Trace
    Line | Method
->>  445 | checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation in org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   3483 | checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation in org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl
...

and the following error is shown at IDEA console:
    javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(SessionImpl.java:3483)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1399)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1394)
    at org.grails.plugin.hibernate.support.GrailsOpenSessionInViewInterceptor.postHandle(GrailsOpenSessionInViewInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter.postHandle(WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPostHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1078)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
...

My code is as follow:
GenericGatePass.withTransaction { TransactionStatus status ->
        def currentDateForCode = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy").format(new Date())

        try {
            ...

            if (gatePassInstance.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)) {
                // update permit application

                cartContentList.each { cc ->
                    def cartContent = cc.getValue()
                    def permitInstance = genericGatePassService.getPermitApplicationByPermitNo(cartContent.get("cartIndex")?.toString())
                    ...

                    if (permitInstance.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)) {
                        ...
                        applicationHistoryService.addApprovalToHistory(permitInstance.id, inputParams)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            redirect(action: "show", id: gatePassInstance?.id)
            return
        } catch (Exception ex) {
                status.setRollbackOnly()
            flash.error = ex.message
        }
    }

here if I comment the permitInstance.save() block then no errors happen.
